# Batch file always echoes the same thing regardless of input

Tags: windows, git, batch-file, command-line

I'm attempting to write a batch script to retrieve the latest tag from a git repository and make a new one. The arguments to the script can be "patch", "major" or "minor". Here's my code so far:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

call :contains %1


exit /B %ERRORLEVEL%

:contains
SETLOCAL
set acceptable_versions[0]=patch
set acceptable_versions[1]=minor
set acceptable_versions[2]=major
:: loop over acceptable versions and compare to first argument
for /l %%n in (0,1,2) do (
  if %~1==!acceptable_versions[%%n]! call :create_and_push_tag && exit /B 0
)
echo Argument must be "patch" "minor" or "major"
exit /B 1
ENDLOCAL

:create_and_push_tag
SETLOCAL
echo Retrieving tags
call git fetch --tag
call git describe --abbrev=0 --tags 
exit /B 0
ENDLOCAL
```

No matter which argument I input the output is always

```
Retrieving tags
patch
```

I'm new to batch scripting so I'm probably making an obvious mistake but any help would be appreciated. And yes, I know the code is incomplete.

EDITED TO ADD: I *know* cmd.exe is inferior but the point is to use it in this particular case. It's fun to bash () windows but not particularly helpful.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and lose cmd.exe, use bash. Also, you probably want just `git` rather than `call git`, git's not a batch file.

Comment: unfortunately using cmd is kinda the point, I'm retooling an existing project to play nicely with windows machines

Comment: Changed to just using `git`, though, thanks

Comment: Did that do it?

Comment: It behaves the same way

Comment: You cannot break out of a `FOR /L` like that.  The `FOR /L` will iterate all three times regardlesss of you using `&& exit /b 0`.

Comment: well that's annoying

Comment: @Squashman, the loop is finishing in the background but with an empty body, so this should not be the problem. However, there is a condition `if %~1==!acceptable_versions[%%n]!` (which should actually read `if "%~1"=="!acceptable_versions[%%n]!"`), but the following command `call :create_and_push_tag` just always the same, independent from the preceding condition. By the way, `call git` should be `git`…